# uniVocity parsers to handle two files

Tags: java, csv, univocity

I am using uniVocity in order to parse two different files. For every line of the first file I need to iterate through file 2 in order to make some comparisons.

```
    RowListProcessor rowProcessor = new RowListProcessor();

    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
    settings.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true);
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    settings.setSkipEmptyLines(true);

    CsvParser file1Parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    CsvParser file2Parser = new CsvParser(settings);
```

Do I need to use different `CsvParserSettings` for the two parsers, or is there some other way to define `rowProcessor`s?

Also how can I read the files line by line in order to perform the operations I need in each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same settings, but will need new `rowProcessor` for each parser if you are going to run both parsers at the same time.

```
RowListProcessor anotherRowProcessor = new RowListProcessor();
settings.setRowProcessor(anotherRowProcessor); //using the same settings object here
CsvParser file2Parser = new CsvParser(settings);
```

However, from what you described it seems you'd be fine by not using a row processor and just iterate over the rows produced by each parser. In this case just get rid of the row processors, and do this:

```
CsvParser file1Parser=new CsvParser(settings);
CsvParser file2Parser=new CsvParser(settings);

file1Parser.beginParsing(file1);
file2Parser.beginParsing(file2);

String[] rowOfParser1;
String[] rowOfParser2;

while((rowOfParser1 = file1Parser.parseNext()) != null){
    rowOfParser2 = file2Parser.parseNext();
    //do whatever you need to do with the rows.
}

//only need to call this if you are not reading both inputs entirely
file1Parser.stopParsing();
file2Parser.stopParsing();
```

Hope this helps.